# NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, label

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que quiero imprimir un texto con label en una ventana tkinter, pero esto me aparece

el comienzo del codigo es:

```
from tkinter import *
interfaz = Tk()
interfaz.title("ventana")
interfaz.geometry("600x300")

#funciones
```

(no las puedo poner porque la pagina no permite que esto sea mayormente codigo)

```
#etiquetas

labelExample = tk.Label(va, text = "This is a label")
labelExample.grid(row = 0, column = 2, columnspan = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

(el tk.label vive en la funcion "va" que es una ventana invocada desde un boton)

#botones

```
interfaz.mainloop()
```

(fin del codigo)

y este es el problema que me sale:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users-\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 54, in
>
> labelExample = tk.Label(va, text = "This is a label") NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Hola buen día, dado que estas importando todo, no es necesario usar tk en `tk.Label`, únicamente usa Label().

Answer (score 0):

Debido a la forma en la que estás importando `tkinter`, no queda definido ningún identificador y si todas las funciones en el espacio de nombres, entonces te refieres a ellas sin prefijo alguno, tal como lo haces con `Tk()` al inicio del script.

Debo decir, en este punto, que yo regularmente recomiendo seguir la otra vía, e importar el módulo de esta forma:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Entonces el módulo queda asociado al nombre local `tk` y te refieres a los identificadores dentro de `tkinter` con `tk.xxx`.

En tu caso, tendrías que cambiar la creación de la ventana a:

```
interfaz = tk.Tk()
```

En adelante, cualquier otra referencia a `tkinter` iría prefijada por el nombre local `tk` (o el que decidas ponerle).

La razón por la que prefiero esto es porque mantienes el espacio de nombres más ordenado y es menos propenso a errores.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar otra forma de importación como esta tambien. ten en cuenta que dependiendo de la forma de importación , deberás armar la sintáxis luego.

```
import tkinter 

interfaz = tkinter.Tk()
interfaz.title ("ventana")
interfaz.geometry ("600x300")

labelExample = tkinter.Label (va , text = "this is a label")
labelExample.grid (row =0 , columnspan =1 , padx =10 , pady =10)


interfaz.mainloop()
```